# Common/idiomatic ways of saying "Tell me if there's anything you need help with."

Tags: modismos, méxico, preguntas

I am trying to find natural-sounding ways of saying things like: "*Let me know if there is anything you need help with*" or "*Tell me if there's something I can help you with*".

In my basic Spanish, I would probably just come up with something like "*Dime si necesitas ayuda con algo*" o "*Dime si hay algo con que yo puedo ayudarte.*"

But I am wondering how native speakers might communicate this. What are common/idiomatic ways of expressing this? (particularly in Mexico or other Central American countries)

Thanks.

Comment: Those sound pretty good to me, especially the first.  (My Spanish is Mexican influenced.)  For the second one I guess I'd say it a tiny bit different: "Dime si hay algo con que te pueda ayudar."  Flows better for me.  Also, note the subjunctive.

Comment: I am from Spain, but I think there won't be many regional differences in this case. Your sentences sound pretty good. I would say "Dime si te puedo ayudar en algo", which is almost the same as your proposals, but using the "en" preposition instead of "con".

Comment: @Charlie - Yes, I like your preposition.  It sounds much nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the options that you propose are valid, only that in the second case I would use the subjunctive instead of the indicative, and I would elide the pronoun *yo*. I would also consider the variant *lo que* for the relative pronoun, although it is not mandatory:

> Dime si hay algo con (lo) que **pueda** ayudarte.

I suggest another version of the phrase where the word order changes a little bit:

> Dime si puedo ayudarte con/en algo.

Another option, rephrasing it completely, and kind of shorter:

> Dime si puedo hacer algo por ti.

This last version has a wider application, but you can use it in the context that you need.

Comment: Hazme saber si necesitas ayuda. Te ayudo? Dime si te ayudo con eso/con algo. Let me know if there is anything you need help with - Hazme saber si hay algo con lo que necesitas ayuda. Tell me if there's something I can help you with - Dime si hay algo en lo que te pueda ayudar. - Etc. ad infinitum.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by Alicia, you might take into consideration the regional variant in Argentina and Uruguay: **decime** instead of **dime**. It can be used in all the previous cases.

> - Decime si hay algo con (lo) que pueda ayudarte.
> - Decime si puedo ayudarte con/en algo.
> - Decime si puedo hacer algo por ti.

Comment: But OP put Mexico in the tags and in the question!

Comment: Si, es verdad, pero mi madre es de Buenos Aires y quiero visitar en la futura, asi que es util tambien :)

Answer (score 2):

As i remember in some mexican tv shows (as Chespirito, el Chavo or Cantinflas movies), is more used the sentences with *Digame* (with the pronoun *Usted*) so you could said something like:

*Digame si le ayudo con algo* or *Digame si necesita mi ayuda* or *Digame en que le puedo ayudar* etc.